# Writing a model to database, am I doing this right?

Tags: c#, sql

I've come up with this code to write the values of a model into my database but i wonder if what I'm doing here is the correct way of doing it.

The reason i came up with this; I want to reuse the SaveData method for other processes to write data to database. In this post I've only added one, SignUp. In order to make a reusable method I'd have to make it work for different database tables, the easiest i came up with is to create a datatable in each process and just send that to the SaveData method.

Altough as a newbie I'm excited to have come up with this mostly by myself i do wonder if this is an efficient or even acceptable way of achieving this.

In this first section i move the values from the model to the datatable.

```
    public static void SignUp(AccountSignUp model)
    {
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(Int32)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn ("Username", typeof(string)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn ("FirstName", typeof(string)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn ("LastName", typeof(string)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn ("EmailAddress", typeof(string)));
        DataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PasswordHash", typeof(string)));

        DataRow DataRow = DataTable.NewRow();
        DataRow["UserName"] = model.UserName;
        DataRow["PasswordHash"] = model.Password;
        DataRow["Firstname"] = model.FirstName;
        DataRow["LastName"] = model.LastName;
        DataRow["EmailAddress"] = model.EmailAddress;
        DataTable.Rows.Add(DataRow);
        DataAccess.SaveData(DataTable);
    }
```

Here's the method to write the datatable to the database:

```
    public static void SaveData(DataTable data)
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString)) 
        {
            copy.DestinationTableName = "UserAccounts"; //WIP/Debugging 
            copy.WriteToServer(data);
        }
    }
```

Is this a good way to do this? or is there a more efficient way? I feel like you should be able to pass the model directly to the database as a row or something without first creating a new datatable.

Anyway thanks for reading any help is appreciated!

Comment: _"I feel like you should be able to pass the model directly to the database as a row or something"_ - yes, with Entity Framework

Comment: Using SqlBulkCopy to insert just one row is an overhead.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov What would be a better way to do this then?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using a DataTable to store the values from your model and then passing it to the SaveData method using SqlBulkCopy is a reasonable way to insert data into a database. It can be especially efficient when dealing with bulk inserts.

However, if you are dealing with a single record insert (as in your SignUp method), using an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) tool might provide a simpler and more straightforward solution such as below :

Create a model named **AccountSignUp** having these required fields
and pass it to the method SignUp(AccountSignUp model)
then store them in your account table them using the Add method and save changes using context.SaveChanges()

```
public static void SignUp(AccountSignUp model)
{
    using (var context = new YourDbContext())
    {
        var account = new Account
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            PasswordHash = model.Password,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress
        };

        context.UserAccounts.Add(account);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You can define your dbcontext as below :

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```